# Conically shaped pit

Tags: equation-solving

[image]

I need help with b. I tried to use the find root but it didn't work !

Comment: I tried F[r_] = 5000 + 25*Pi*r^2 + 50*Pi*r^(Sqrt[r^2 - (22500/(Pi*r^4))])
FindRoot[5000 + 25*Pi*r^2 + 
  50*Pi*r^(Sqrt[r^2 - (22500/(Pi*r^4))]), {r, 0}]

Comment: Then I tried based off the derivative of r from the cost function:100*50+50*pi*r*sqrt(h^2+r^2) +25pir^2 

Roots[2 r^2 Sqrt[22500/(\[Pi]^2*r^4) + r^2] + 2 r^2 - 
   22500/(\[Pi]^2*r^4) == 0, r]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

areaSides = Pi*r*Sqrt[r^2 + h^2];
areaTop = Pi*r^2;
volume = Pi*r^2*h/3;

cost = 100*volume + 50*areaSides + 25*areaTop;

solh = Solve[volume == 50, h][[1]]

(* {h -> 150/(π r^2)} *)
```

The radius of the pit in meters is

```
solr = Solve[{D[cost /. solh, r] == 0, r > 0}, r][[1]] // N

(* {r -> 2.84461} *)
```

The depth of the pit in meters is

```
h /. solh /. solr

(* 5.90061 *)
```

The minimum cost in dollars is

```
cost /. solh /. solr

(* 8562.48 *)
```

Verifying,

```
Minimize[{cost, volume == 50, r > 0, h > 0}, {r, h}] // N

(* {8562.48, {r -> 2.84461, h -> 5.90061}} *)
```